# Is a Collection of Expression<Func<T, TProp>> possible?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections, expression

Given this code:

```
public class PaginationModel<T> : BaseModel
{
    public List<T> Rows { get; set; }

    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }

    public void AddColumn<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> column)
    {

    }
}
```

I want to be able to use the code

```
leadListOutputModel.AddColumn(x => x.DateCreated);
```

And then in my MVC view loop through a collection of columns and invoke the expression against an object, however because TProp is inferred in the method call it cannot seem to be stored as a generic field, e.g.

```
    private List<Expression<Func<T, TProp>>> columns = new List<Expression<Func<T, TProp>>>();
```

Can anyone think of a way around this without using object or losing the generic benefits?

--- EDIT

I'm trying to do two things,

Firstly, I'm passing over a 'SortBy' paramater to my Controller which takes the name of the property of the string, currently being extracted via ((MemberExpression)expression).Member.Name, and secondly I'd like to use the Func to extract the value of that field in my MVC view.

The reason being I am making a paginated grid which I would like be have configurable columns using a nice syntax in the controller, such as the AddColumn example I gave. I'd like to look through the Columns to create the header row, then in my collection of Models loop through those and invoke the Func against them to pull out the value.

Comment: I would say `List<Expression<Func<T, object>>>`, but you suggest that loses the benefit of a generic `TProp`. Could you elaborate? What benefit does it have?

Comment: Re: Your edit: Yes; I've done that before.  You need a collection of non-generic interfaces, with generic implementations created by the generic AddColumn method.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to *do* with the columns afterwards? You can't really use any compile-time information about the result type later, as it can vary from call to call:

```
AddColumn(x => x.SomeInt32Value);
AddColumn(x => x.SomeDateTimeValue);
```

If those are going to be stored in the same collection, you'd *have* to either cast or use a more general form anyway.

You might want to consider using:

```
public void AddColumn(Expression<Func<T, object>> column)
```

It will still be safe in terms of the "source" type... you'll lose the "result" type, but I don't think that would be useful for you anyway.

Comment: That would prevent you from adding properties or functions that return value types directly (as opposed to passing an auto-boxing lambda).

Comment: @SLaks: Well you're not going to be able to use method group conversions anyway given that it's using expression trees rather than delegates... so it would only be an issue if you had other expression trees already built.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to make a collection where each instance has a *different* `TProp`.
That is not directly possible.

Instead, you can make generic class that implements a non-generic interface.
You can then create a collection of the non-generic interface, and add instances of the generic class to the collection from a generic method.

For an example of this technique, see my [ExcelExporter library](https://github.com/SLaks/ExcelExporter/blob/master/ExcelExporter/ExcelExport.cs#L15) and its generic [SheetBase class](https://github.com/SLaks/ExcelExporter/blob/master/ExcelExporter/Exporters/SheetBase.cs).